# Ionic service.js don't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a problem with an ionic app. I create a `service.js` file where I want to create same factory.

In my `app.js` I have this line:

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'app.controllers', 'app.routes', 'app.directives','app.services'])
```

where I load controllers, routes, directives and services.

This is my `services.js`

```
angular.module('app.services', [])

.factory('MyService', function () {
  return {
    sayHello: function () {
      return "HELLO";
    }
  }
});
```

Where create new factory called `MyService` with a function sayHello.

In my `controller.js` I have this code

```
angular.module('app.controllers', ['app.services'])     

.controller('iMontiCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams',
function ($scope, $stateParams, MyService) {

    $messaggio = "Test"; 
    alert($messaggio);
    $scope.messaggio1 = MyService.sayHello();
    alert($messaggio+"2");
}])
```

This code show only `alert($messaggio)` but not `alert($messaggio+"2")`

If I comment `Myservice.sayHello()` it's work fine.

I also check `index.html` include:

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>


<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/routes.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
```

But I don't see problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to inject `MyService` in DI array before using it in controller factory function

```
.controller('iMontiCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'MyService', //<-- inject service here
function ($scope, $stateParams, MyService) {
```